# ProgressBar is not center in RelativeLayout when a ListView inside layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-progressbar, android-relativelayout

I have the following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp" />

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a toolbar and a listView below it. Until I populate the list I want to display a ProgressBar in center of the layout. I set centerInParent but it doesn't work. The progressBar is displayed over the toolbar.

[image]

I tried to put the progressBar inside a LinearLayout but I get the same result. How can I center it?

**Edit**

This is the `toolbar_layout.xml` :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16dp"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16dp"
    style="@style/ScreenTitleStyle"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: post your toolbar layout code here.

Comment: @MehulSolanki I edited my question and added the toolbar_layout in question.

Comment: I added the answer below. check that snipped. if that will work then uncomment your toolbar that commented and delete Toolbar that I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below snipped

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
   <!-- <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />-->
   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:padding="16dp"
       android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your list view `hight` and `width` must be `match_parent`.

Comment: That was the problem, the height was wrap_content and match_parent resolved the centering problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"` from your `ProgressBar`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        layout="@layout/bb" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Still not working. With android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" it is displayed below the toolbar but not in center of the screen as I want. Without it, the progressBar is displayed over the toolbar .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a constraint layout the following should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp" />

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```